# Is it possible to change 'http://localhost:8080/myapplication' to something like 'http://myApp/' in tomcat7?

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat7

I have deployed the application in Tomcat 7 in my local system.
when i run the application,url path is coming like 'http://localhost:8080/myapplication'

Is it possible to change 'http://localhost:8080/myapplication' to something like 'http://myApp/'?

Answer (score 2):

No, generally not.

A URL pattern looks like `scheme://domain:port/path?query_string#fragment_id`, so your pattern would use the domain / host name "myApp".

You could of course set up a host name called "myApp" and then call your application with the root context (similar like many web sites work - e.g. google is simply called with "http://www.google.com"), but I am not sure if this is what you want ...

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why you would want to do it, but it is possible to do. However, it is not all dependent on Tomcat. You would need to:

1. Alias myApp to localhost (in unix/linux you would add `127.0.0.1       myApp` to /etc/hosts)
2. Change the port that Tomcat listens to from port 8080 to port 80
3. Deploy your application as ROOT.war or explicitly mount it as /

This will make your application respond as either `http://localhost/` or `http://myApp/`. This happens because when you use the default port (80) there is no need to explicitly specify it and the root context is mounted as /. Also since you have aliased myApp with localhost, you can now use them interchangeably.

Remember, this will only work on your local machine though and will not make it accessible to others on your network. For that you would have to play around with DNS and such.

Answer (score 0):

Yes; you can do it by creating a [virtual host](https://www.google.com/search?q=virtual+host).

Answer (score 0):

Sure, but is that *really* what you want? The part after `http://` is the *hostname* and the part after that is the *context*... I think you're perhaps confusing these two concepts?

If you insist, then just add/edit the line

```
127.0.0.1   localhost myApp
```

in your `/etc/hosts` or `\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` file and modify the tomcat config to 1) respond to your webapp on the ROOT context and 2) listen on port 80 rather than 8080.

Cheers,